# Optimizing jQuery Spoiler Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<button id="b1" type="button">Show Spoiler</button>
<p id="p1" style="display:none"> This is a damn paragraph.</p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
function bindEvent(element, eventName, eventHandler) {
    var el = $(element)[0];
    if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, false)
    } else if (el.attachEvent) {
        el.attachEvent('on'+eventName, eventHandler);
    }
}
bindEvent('#b1', 'click', function() {
    $('#p1').toggle('blind');
    if ($('#b1').text() == 'Show Spoiler') {
        $('#b1').text('Hide Spoiler');
    } else if ($('#b1').text() == 'Hide Spoiler') {
        $('#b1').text('Show Spoiler');
    }

});
```

I'm new to jQuery and Javascript so I made this simple script to show and hide a paragraph and to change the button texts whenever clicked. My problem is that this seems a bit clunky. Is there a better, shorter, and simpler way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, jQuery already normalizes DOM event listeners for you across browsers, so your `bindEvent` function isn't necessary anymore. Here's the short way, using some stuff you can look up yourself in the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/), to do what you're doing.

```
var $b1 = $('#b1')
  , $p1 = $('#p1')
  , hideText = 'Hide Spoiler'
  , showText = 'Show Spoiler'

$b1.on('click',function() {
    var text = $b1.text()
      , newText = text === showText ? hideText : showText
    $p1.toggle('blind')
    $b1.text(newText)
})
```

Here are a few things to notice:

- Your example function assumes a single spoiler `#p1` and a single reveal button `#b1`. In production, this will probably be based on classes, like `.spoiler` and `.spoiler-trigger`, and there will be multiple spoilers on a page. In that case, you'll need to get the value of `this`. In this example let's assume that the reveal button is always a sibling of the spoiler itself.

  ```
  $('.spoiler-trigger').on('click',function() {
      var $this = $(this)
        , $thisSpoiler = $this.siblings('.spoiler').eq(0)
        , text = $this.text()
        , newText = text === showText ? hideText : showText
      $thisSpoiler.toggle('blind')
      $this.text(newText)
  })
  ```
- The jQuery `.on` method is the cross-browser event listener function that you'll want to start using.
- jQuery selectors we use repeatedly, like `$(this)` or `$('#b1')`,  should be cached in local variables for performance.
- I'm using a ternary conditional instead of an if statement to determine what the show/hide text should be, because in this very simple case I consider it more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, works perfectly. However I have a question on why you can omit the semicolon such as at `$thisSpoiler.toggle('blind')` and `$this.text(newText)`

Comment: I write JavaScript that is very low on semicolons. It's a personal choice that helps me stick to simpler code and notice logic mistakes. JavaScript is an odd language because its official spec requires semicolons, but that same spec includes an "Automatic Semicolon Insertion" routine that makes them unnecessary in all but ambiguous cases. You might speak to others who think my code is stupid. [Here is an article](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons) explaining this slightly controversial subject. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make this work with simple 3 lines of code using awesome jquery. trigger the button click event, and on click -> toggle the element 'P'. This should help : [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/L2AcF/2/)

```
$("#b1").click(function () {
      $("#p1").toggle('slow');
    });​
```